# Are there standard ways to accomplish localized date components on Android such as 1s, 1m, 1h, 1d, 1w, 1week, etc

Tags: java, android, date, localization

I am looking for a standard utility provided by Android or Java to localize date components. An example of a date component in English and a Spanish localization would be:

English (en):

- 3w
- 3 wks
- 3 weeks

Spanish (es):

- 3sem
- 3 sem
- 3 semanas

You can easily accomplish the above in any common language using [`DateComponentsFormatter` on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter). I am looking for an Android / Java equivalent.

Comment: Are you asking for something like `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: @EmreEran FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Asking for libraries is off-topic here on Stack Overflow. Try the sister site, https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I posted a [feature request for this](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra/issues/111) on the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project, for the `Seconds`, `Minutes`, `Hours`, `Days`, [`Weeks`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Weeks.html), [`Months`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Months.html), and `Years` classes.

Answer (score 3):

My library [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) supports it:

Use for example:

`String formatted = 
  PrettyTime.of(Locale.US).print(Duration.of(3, CalendarUnit.WEEKS), TextWidth.WIDE);`

See the [API](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/PrettyTime.html#print-net.time4j.Duration-net.time4j.format.TextWidth-), there is support for actually 89 languages. The localized data are based on the CLDR-repository maintained by Unicode consortium.